# What is the meaning of this wooden symbol found in a basement?

Tags: symbolism

I have no idea if this is the right place to ask this, but it felt like the best bet.  I discovered this crudely carved wooden symbol/cross in a basement (see picture below).  Any idea what it might represent?

It doesn't seem to be any [common Christian cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_cross_variants) given the bent horn-like things on top.  I didn't find any other symbols or wooden bits nearby so I assume this is the whole thing.  It's possible it might be some tool or jig used in construction, but I can't imagine what purpose it could serve.

Thanks for your help, and let me know if there's any additional information I can add.

[image: carved wooden symbol/cross in dark basement]

Comment: This might not be anything at all. I could be wrong, but I've never seen anything like it. Providing more context, including why you think it's not a structural part of the house, would be useful.

Comment: It certainly could be nothing. I realize now that "pipe space" is a more accurate term than "basement," so perhaps it had some use in that context? I found it lying on a duct amidst some other debris (broken lightbulbs, insulation, etc.), so if it had a structural use at one point, it was no longer being used like that.

Comment: Yeah, you may want to ask on some forum or another that specializes in construction or renovation. My bets is that it's functional, not a symbol of anything.

Answer (score 3):

#### Gothic Arch Window Frame

I suspect that the best bet for this bit of wood is that was once part of a completely unmythical window frame. This bit would have been in the middle, and there would have been a larger, exterior frame around it. There are *loads* of different styles, sizes, and levels of fanciness to these things. The image below is illustrative rather than diagnostic for a particular style or make.

[image: antiques.com]